# Enable token based auth in WebAPI based service with SSL enabled

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, jwt, owin

I have a WebAPI/OWIN based service with custom middleware for certificate based authentication. Currently it requires SSL cert to connect. Now I have a requirement of adding a support for token based auth so instead of the certificate, the client will add JWT token in the request header. So I added another middleware to handle the tokens but the server rejects the incoming requests from the HTTP layer with error 12044 (A certificate is required to complete client authentication).

Is, the way I am handling the tokens in the custom middleware, the problem ? Should I use the UseOAuthBearerTokens or UseOAuthAuthorizationServer instead?

I have looked on the web but couldn't find scenario quite like this but I am sure some if not a lot of people would have encountered it.

What is the standard way of fixing it or how do I workaround this problem ?

Comment: What about changing custom middleware handling certificate based authentication to skip authentication in case certificate is not valid and there is a bearer token present in headers?

Comment: Thats what I have right now, but this requires client to send a fake certificate along with a token. This should work but it sounds like a hack and I am not quite sure if this is the standard protocol.

Comment: Can you post implementations and configurations? Without it is very hard to help.

Comment: yeah makes sense. I have actually found out the culprit here. The problem was there was a module verifying the requests IIS receives and it denied any request without having a certificate. I couldn't figure out why my request with JWT doesn't even reach the middlewares because it was done so early in the processing. Thanks for looking.

Comment: Okay. Good you have solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future readers hitting this weird issue.

There was a module intercepting and filtering the IIS requests early in the pipeline. It also performs the SSL negotiations, basic certificate validations and such.

This was initially designed to prevent any requests without valid certificates and it is not even a part of repository anymore and just used a binary reference.